# MS Teams trying to connect to a network drive

Tags: microsoft-teams

Everytime I start MS Teams is takes forever. After a few minutes I get an error about connecting to one of ours NAS boxes. This goes on for 5 or 6 times. I think I have previously shared a file direct from the NAS so I am guess Teams is trying to connect to it to.

Does anyone know how I can either stop Teams trying to connect or remove the file I have shared?

I have tried to look at all the files I have shared but I can't find a way of looking at all the files I have shared in one view. It will take forever to go through every chat and view the files which are shared.

I am on Mac OS btw.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: See if you can able to find the link in the Teams and remove it. Also see if you can use the utility like Process Monitor (Procmon) for Mac which will tell you under the Teams process which other sub process opens up or tries to connect... Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Same problem here, no solution yet :(